# onLocationChanged is not called After JellyBean onwards version

Tags: android, location

my below code working in every devices except android 4.1 and android 4.2 versions. i already tried many things and searched about that..in samsung forum, it also said its not working see this [Link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/after-jellybean-locationmanager-with-network_provider-is-not-working-until-rebooting-the-device-/77/233772?boardName=GeneralB&startId=zzzzz~)

```
 mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000, 100, this);




public void onLocationChanged(Location newBestLocation) {

        System.out.println("On Location Change Call.......");
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        boolean best = isBetterLocation(newBestLocation, currentLocation);
        if (best) {
            currentLocation = newBestLocation;
        }
        locationUpdater.onLocationUpdateReceived(currentLocation);
    }
```

if anyone know the solution for that then please let me know about that.

Comment: "not working" is a useless description of your symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager behavior for Location update frequency in relationship to the minTime and minDistance parameters changed in Android 4.1.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html:

> Prior to Jellybean, the minTime parameter was only a hint, and some location provider implementations ignored it. From Jellybean and onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both the minTime and minDistance parameters.

I would suspect that your minDistance = 100 may be causing lack of updates on 4.1 and above, when Android did trigger updates on 4.0 and below (potentially incorrectly).  Try changing both values to = 0 and see what happens - you should see an update fairly frequently:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

You'll have to play with these parameters until you get something that meets your application requirements for location update frequency, while conserving battery life, and has consistent behavior on all versions of Android you want to support.

Given the above limitations, you might want to consider switching to the new Fused Location Provider:
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

...and more specifically, the PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY priority:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY